# Not able to establish Aurora Postgres Connection in Glue (InvalidInputException: Unable to resolve any valid connection)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue, amazon-aurora

I have created Aurora Postgresql database and i want to test the connection using Glue.
I have navigated to Connections tab in glue and adde the connection settings accordingly.
After that i tried to test the connection and i am getting InvalidInputException: Unable to resolve any valid connection error not sure why.

I have added checked the connection string also :
To connect to an Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL instance of the employee database, specify the endpoint for the database instance, the port, and the database name:
jdbc:postgresql://database-1-instance-1.cvpj15ycqt3h.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/initial_db

[image]

Also i have added referencing security groups also.
[image]

Below are the screenshots where in Glue i was trying to establish connection.
[image]

[image]
Also i was able to connect with sql client to the database.
Can anyone help me whats wrong in it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try serverfault.com. “I can’t make a network connection” is not a software engineering question.

Comment: @anothermh sorry i didnt get what u said.

Comment: WHy are you using Glue over RDS Data Client within a Lambda function? Just wondering (assuming you are using the Serverless Version that supports the Data Client)

Comment: @smac2020 i am not using lambda function here. i am trying to establish connection with Aurora Postgresql using Glue. I tried connecting Aurora Postgresql using sql client locally. It worked succesfully. Not sure why i am getting error in Glue

Comment: I typically use RDS Data Client where possible for RDS interaction.

Comment: @smac2020 yeah using any client i was able to connect to Aurora. but it is giving error when i am trying with Glue.This is JDBS connectyion string inside Postgresql connection: jdbc:postgresql://database-1-instance-1.cvpj15ycqt3h.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/initial_db